# Scraping a webpage and related subsequent page using R or Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, web-scraping, nlp

I want do do some NLP on song lyrics to categorize mood by decades. Now, given a given lyrics page for a specific artist, such as The Smiths, I have the top page displaying all song names:

https://www.azlyrics.com/s/smiths.html

Reel Around the Fountain \n

You've Got Everything Now \n

.....

Where each title is a link to the actual lyrics page

https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/smiths/reelaroundthefountain.html
https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/smiths/youvegoteverythingnow.html

Now, how would one go about scraping all lyrics from https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/smiths/XXX.html where XXX is the title on the first page https://www.azlyrics.com/s/smiths.html.

Grateful for any help! And as I wrote, R or Python. Doesn't really matter. Preferably, I would like each lyrics to be saved in separate *.txt files.

I tried this:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
list =[title1, title2, .....]
for x in list:
    url= "https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/smiths?x".format(str)
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    for span in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'views-field views-field-created'}) :
        print r.get_text()
```

But failed. It works if the subsequent pages are numbered though.

Comment: You can't post a problem with no code and ask people to write it for you. The site is to help people after they've made an attempt to tackle the problem.

Comment: I suggest you to extract all the hrefs with the `Rcrawler` package from the Iframe and after you should use `Rvest` to take the text or use `Rselenium`.

Comment: @EricTruett I did try. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# GET request to scrape the page for lyric links
r = requests.get('https://www.azlyrics.com/s/smiths.html')
# create soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
# base url
url = 'https://www.azlyrics.com/'
# list comprehension to get all the links to the song lyrics
album_list = [url+a['href'].strip('..') for a in soup.find(id='listAlbum').findAll('a', href=True)]

for song in album_list:
    # do stuff with song
    # resp = requests.get(song)
    # song_soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    # etc.
```

Comment: This is really nice! Thank you, @Chris!

Answer (score 1):

In R, we can use `rvest`.

First, we get all the links of lyrics.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.azlyrics.com/s/smiths.html"
all_links <- url %>%
              read_html() %>%
              html_nodes('div.listalbum-item a') %>%
              html_attr('href') %>%
         {paste0('https://www.azlyrics.com/', sub('../', '', ., fixed = TRUE))}
```

Then get lyrics from every page in `all_links`.

```
all_lyrics <- purrr::map(all_links, ~.x %>%read_html() %>% html_nodes('div') %>% .[[20]] %>% html_text())
```